Bond lengths of M-CH2 vs M-O
Are there any known (ionic) solid structures with an anion site occupied by either $\ce{O^2-}$ or $\ce{(CH2)^2-}$ ?
If the answer is "yes", I'd like to know which anion forms shorter bond to the metal. $\ce{M-C}$ in case of $\ce{M_x(CH2)_y}$ or $\ce{M-O}$ in case of $\ce{M_xO_y}$ ?
